# span spacing between header and description after BR tag

Tags: css

```
<span id="headerw">Header Here</span><br>
<span id="descw">The other description comes here..</span>
```

The br only works as a breaker, I need to add a margin between the header and the description. how can I do that? I'm displaying as block in the container, and added margin-top to the descw.. but nothing is working.

Comment: Don't use a `br` tag for spacing, use margins or padding. My guess is that you are getting some margin-collapse. JSFiddle please

Comment: Post your CSS and HTML. A complete example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be using  `<span>` tags for headers. You should be using `<h1> - <h6>` and `<p>` for the description. This will give you margin between your elements.